# Optimal way to find manager phone number whose subordinates live in more than one city in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying Find the phone numbers of all managers whose direct report hierarchy live in more than 1 city in `O(n)` time complexity. Below is my approach which is using with Time Complexity `O(M*N)` where M is the number of managers and N is the Number of employess.
Can someone please help me with `O(N)` solution for this problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class EmployeePhoneNums {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        String[][] emps2 = new String[][]{
     //"EmployeeID", "ManagerID", "City", "Phone number"
                {"e1", "e1", "SF", "phone-1"},
                {"e2", "e1", "SF", "phone-2"},
                {"e3", "e1", "SF", "phone-3"},
                {"e4", "e2", "SF", "phone-4"},
                {"e5", "e2", "PH", "phone-5"},
                {"e6", "e3", "NY", "phone-6"}                   
        };
        Map<String, String> phoneNums = getmanagerPhoneNums(emps2);
        System.out.println(phoneNums);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getmanagerPhoneNums(String[][] input) {
        Map<String, String> managerPhoneNums = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> phoneMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> cityMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Set<String>> mgrEmps = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> managers = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (String[] emp : input) {
            phoneMap.put(emp[0], emp[3]);
            cityMap.put(emp[0], emp[2]);
            managers.add(emp[1]);
            if (emp[0].equals(emp[1]))
                continue;
            else {
                mgrEmps.putIfAbsent(emp[1], new HashSet<>());
                mgrEmps.get(emp[1]).add(emp[0]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mgrEmps);
        Queue<String> managersQ = new LinkedList<>(managers);
        while (!managersQ.isEmpty()) {
            String manager = managersQ.poll();
            bfs(manager, mgrEmps, phoneMap, cityMap, managerPhoneNums);
        }
        return managerPhoneNums;
    }

    public static void bfs(String manager, Map<String, Set<String>> mgrEmps, Map<String, String> phoneMap, Map<String, String> cityMap, Map<String, String> resultPhoneNums) {
        Queue<String> reportees = new LinkedList<>();
        if (mgrEmps.containsKey(manager)) reportees.addAll(mgrEmps.get(manager));
        Set<String> cities = new HashSet<>();
        while (!reportees.isEmpty()) {
            int size = reportees.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                String emp = reportees.poll();
                if (mgrEmps.get(emp) != null && mgrEmps.get(emp).size() > 0) reportees.addAll(mgrEmps.get(emp));
                cities.add(cityMap.get(emp));
                if (cities.size() > 1) break;
            }
            if (cities.size() > 1) {
                resultPhoneNums.put(manager, phoneMap.get(manager));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The result `{e1=phone-1, e2=phone-2}` does not match the requirements described. Shouldn't only `e2` appear in the result, because the reportees of `e1` both live in SF? And why a string array, wouldn't a custom object `Employee` be much easier?

Comment: @OTUser does 'City' represent the city of the manager or the employee ?

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb city represents employee city

Comment: @Eritrean The requirement is to find out the employees who lives in more than one city in the direct report employee hierarchy without considering the manager city. E1 is in the result because 2 or more employees lives in different city under the hierarchy of e1

Comment: FWIW I think O(n * d) where d is the average depth, is the best you can do. If it was immediate reports only, O(n) is doable. If the depth (max levels of management) is "shallow", then O(n * d) could be considered O(n). Would O(n * d) be OK as O(n)?

Comment: Does "direct reporting hierarchy" include reports' reports? "Direct" implies no, "hierarchy" implies yes, so I would say either "direct reports" or "reporting tree".

Comment: @Bohemian O(N) is possible; but not using the `java.util` collection classes as you need to merge collections and they all implement the `addAll` method by adding elements one-by-one which will take O(N) time. If you create a custom linked list class then you can merge lists in O(1) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem, we can model relationships between employee as a [*Directed Acyclic Graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (*or DAG*) perfectly well.

That will allow finding managers having subordinates that from at least two different cities in a liner time **O(n)**.

For this task we don't need to distinguish between the job-rolls, meaning we can assume that each *employee* can potentially have a *manager* and *subordinates*, the vertex of the graph would represented by the `Employee` class.

There would be no cycles in this *graph* because according to the sample data each *employee* can have *at most* one manager (I'll ignore the case with employee `e1` which happens to be the boss to themself because it doesn't make sense from the perspective of this problem), and connected vertexes would from so-called *N-ary tree*.

There also could be a situation when there are several groups of employee that have no connection with each other, they will form so-called [*connected components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). To ensure that all vertexes would be examined in case when *graph* contains several *connected components*, we need to iterate over the collection of all vertexes and fire the traversal algorithm for every vertex that hasn't been encountered yet.

To understand the logic of traversal, let's consider the following graph of employees.

[image]

As you can see, *Employee-1* (with `id1`) and *Employee-3* (with `id3`) are marked with a green tick denoted that they have subordinates that live in more than one city. Orange arrows represent relation *employee-subordinates*, black arrows - *direction of traversal*.

Let's assume traversal starts from *Employee-1*. To traverse the *graph*, we would use the [*Depth first search algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (*for short DFS*), tweaked a little bit for our purposes. Internally it uses a *stack* data structure (in the code below denoted simply as `stack`). And in every branch when we hit the employee that has no subordinates we need to be able to traverse backwards *propagating the properties* (that's the tweak I've mentioned), and for that we will use another *stack* (denoted as `isBeingVisited`, meaning that we are not done yet with examining the employees it contains because we are traversing their subordinates).

So we are starting by allocating *Employee-1* on the top of the `stack`. Each step of the traversal begins with removing an element from of `stack`. And initially we have only *Employee-1*, it's being removed and since it has subordinates it would be placed on the top of the stack `isBeingVisited`, and its subordinates *Employee-2* and *Employee-3* would be pushed onto the `stack`.

At the beginning of the second step, we have *Employee-3* on the top of the `stack`. It's being removing and allocated on the top of the `isBeingVisited`, while its subordinates *Employee-4* and *Employee-5* would be pushed onto the `stack`.

The third step would start with removal *Employee-5* from the `stack` pushing it onto the `isBeingVisited` and allocating its subordinate *Employee-6* on the `stack`.

Here we've reached the leave of the *N-ary tree*, it means two things: *Employee-6* has no chances to appear in the resulting list (they luck subordinates) and we don't need to push them into `isBeingVisited` (we're done here), but as the last action to tell its manages where they leave. So we are starting to moving backwards, propagating either the properties, which is either a `boolaen` field `isSelected` (denoting whether this employee matches the given criterion), or a *set* of cities (for more detail see the implementation of `propagateSelection()`).

***Note:** in the code logic for backward traversal decoupled from the DFS-implementation, and stack `isBeingVisited` is being processed in one go.*

In short, method `getSelectedEmployee()` fires the traversal by invoking DFS-implementation, method `dfs()`, whenever it encounters the vertex that hasn't been seen before. And when `dfs()` is done, method `select()` performs traversal in the backward direction (from subordinate to manager), propagating the properties of the subordinates and populating the resulting list.

The implementation might of the *graph* might look like this.

```
public static class EmployeeGraph {
    
    private Map<String, Employee> employeeById = new HashMap<>();
    
    public List<Employee> getSelectedEmployee() {
        List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();  // will store the managers having subordinates from more than one city
        Deque<Employee> stack = new ArrayDeque<>(); // will be used for performing traversal in the DFS implementation
        Set<Employee> seen = new HashSet<>();       // is meant to store every encountered vertex
        
        for (Employee next : employeeById.values()) {
            if (!seen.contains(next)) {
                stack.push(next);
                seen.add(next);
                dfs(result, stack, seen);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    private void dfs(List<Employee> result, Deque<Employee> stack, Set<Employee> seen) { // DFS implementation
        Deque<Employee> isBeingVisited = new ArrayDeque<>(); // stack of vertices that are being visited, i.e. managers which subordinates haven't been fully examined
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Employee current = stack.pop();
            List<Employee> subordinates = current.getSubordinates();
            
            if (subordinates.isEmpty()) {
                current.propagateSelection(); // share the city with a direct manager
            } else {
                isBeingVisited.push(current);
                for (Employee subordinate: current.getSubordinates()) {
                    if (seen.add(subordinate)) stack.push(subordinate); // allocating subordinates on the stack
                }
            }
        }
        select(result, isBeingVisited); // examining the properties of managers that has been visited
    }
    
    private void select(List<Employee> result, Deque<Employee> isBeingVisited) {
        while (!isBeingVisited.isEmpty()) {
            Employee manager = isBeingVisited.pop();
            if (manager.isSelected()) result.add(manager); // if manager is marked as selected - add to the result list
            manager.propagateSelection();                  // propagating the properties to the direct manager (if any)
        }
    }
    
    // NOT a part of the Algorithm - convenience-method for initializing the graph by parsing string arguments into instances of employee
    public void addEmployee(String... args) {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            employeeById.computeIfAbsent(args[0], Employee::new);
        } else if (args.length == 4) {
            Employee manager = args[1] != null ? employeeById.computeIfAbsent(args[1], Employee::new) : null;
            
            if (employeeById.containsKey(args[0])) {
                Employee employee = employeeById.get(args[0]);
                
                employee.setManager(manager)
                    .setCity(args[2])
                    .setPhone(args[3]);
            } else {
                employeeById.put(args[0], new Employee(args[0],manager, args[2], args[3]));
            }
            
            if (args[1] != null) {
                manager.addSubordinate(employeeById.get(args[0]));
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    
    public static class Employee {
        private String id;
        private String city;
        private String phone;
        private Employee manager;
        private List<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        private Set<String> subordinateCities = new HashSet<>();
        private boolean isSelected;
        
        public Employee(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public Employee(String id, Employee manager, String city, String phone) {
            this.id = id;
            this.city = city;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.manager = manager;
        }
        
        public void addSubordinate(Employee employee) {
            subordinates.add(employee);
        }
        
        public void propagateSelection() {
            if (manager == null) return;
            
            if (isSelected) {
                manager.setSelected();
            } else {
                shareSubordinateCitiesWithManager();
                manager.trySelect();
            }
        }
        
        public void shareSubordinateCitiesWithManager() {
            Set<String> managersSubCities = manager.subordinateCities;
            managersSubCities.addAll(this.subordinateCities);
            managersSubCities.add(this.city);
        }
        
        public void trySelect() {
            if (subordinateCities.size() >= 2) {
                setSelected();
            }
        }
        
        public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
            return subordinates;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        
        public void setSelected() {
            isSelected = true;
        }
        
        public boolean isSelected() {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public Employee setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
            return this;
        }

        public Employee setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
            return this;
        }

        public Employee setManager(Employee manager) {
            this.manager = manager;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** as suggested by the documentation, as the implementation of the *stack data structure* we need to use classes that implement `Deque` interface (class `Stack` is legacy and shouldn't be used). And the best choice when we need a general purpose implementation of the `Deque` is an `ArrayDeque`, which is backed by the plain array as its name suggests, and its methods are much chipper than corresponding methods of the `LinkedList`. The only reason you can encounter `LinkedList` in the code, espesially while implementing graph traversal algorithms is because since the earlier days of Java it was the only general perpose implementation of the `Queue` and `Deque` interfaces until the Java 6 when `ArrayDeque` was introduced in the JDK.*

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] emps = new String[][]{
        //"EmployeeID", "ManagerID", "City", "Phone number"
        {"e1", null, "SF", "phone-1"},
        {"e2", "e1", "SF", "phone-2"},
        {"e3", "e1", "SF", "phone-3"},
        {"e4", "e2", "SF", "phone-4"},
        {"e5", "e2", "PH", "phone-5"},
        {"e6", "e3", "NY", "phone-6"}
    };

    EmployeeGraph graph = new EmployeeGraph();
    for (String[] arr: emps) graph.addEmployee(arr); // initializing the graph
    
    graph.getSelectedEmployee().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getPhone())); // printing the result - phones of the selected managers
}
```

*Output:*

```
phone-2
phone-1
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tD1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible algo:

1. Maintain two maps  - one for all employees, one for managers
2. Define a class/DS for the manager -- info, reportees, set of distinct cities the reportees belong to
3. The above two can be constructed in O(n)
4. Once you have it, you can iterate (in O(n)) to find all managers with reportees city set with size > 1

Defining class to represent Manager - reportees info like below

```
import java.util.*;

public class MgrReportees {
    private String mngr_id = null;
    private String[] mngr_info = null;
    private List<String> reportee_ids  = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String,String[]> reportee_info = new HashMap<>();
    private Set<String> reportee_city = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void process(String[] emp, Map<String, String[]> all_emp) {
        this.mngr_id = emp[1];
        if(emp[0].equals(emp[1])) { // this one is manager's info
            this.mngr_info = emp;
        }else {
            if(all_emp.containsKey(emp[1])) { // if available, then update manager's ifo
                this.mngr_info = all_emp.get(emp[1]);
            }
            if(!reportee_info.containsKey(emp[0])) {
                reportee_ids.add(emp[0]);
            }
            reportee_info.put(emp[0], emp);
            reportee_city.add(emp[2]);
        }
    }

    public String getMngr_id() {
        return mngr_id;
    }

    public String[] getMngr_info() {
        return mngr_info;
    }

    public List<String> getReportee_ids() {
        return reportee_ids;
    }

    public Map<String, String[]> getReportee_info() {
        return reportee_info;
    }

    public String[] getReportee_info(String reportee_id) {
        return reportee_info.get(reportee_id);
    }

    public Set<String> getReportee_cities() {
        return reportee_city;
    }
}
```

Here's how to construct a map of managers info, notice the two maps - all employees and managers

```
public static Map<String, MgrReportees> constructManagerReportees(String[][] input) {
        Map<String, MgrReportees> mngr_registry = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String[]> employees_registry = new HashMap<>();
        for (String[] emp : input) {
            employees_registry.put(emp[0],emp );
            MgrReportees mgr = mngr_registry.containsKey(emp[1]) ? mngr_registry.get(emp[1])  : new MgrReportees();
            mgr.process(emp, employees_registry);
            mngr_registry.put(emp[1],mgr);
        }

        return mngr_registry;
    }
```

and finally calling it & basic city size check:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] emps2 = new String[][]{
                //"EmployeeID", "ManagerID", "City", "Phone number"
                {"e1", "e1", "SF", "phone-1"},
                {"e2", "e1", "SF", "phone-2"},
                {"e3", "e1", "SF", "phone-3"},
                {"e4", "e2", "SF", "phone-4"},
                {"e5", "e2", "PH", "phone-5"},
                {"e6", "e3", "NY", "phone-6"}
        };
        Map<String, MgrReportees> mgrs = constructManagerReportees(emps2);
        // Find manager's phone with reportees in more than 1 city
        System.out.println("Finding Managers with reportees in more tha 1 city");
        for (Map.Entry<String,MgrReportees> entry : mgrs.entrySet()) {
            MgrReportees r = entry.getValue();
            int cityCount = r.getReportee_cities().size();
            if( cityCount > 1) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Found Manager Id = %s , Mngr Phone = %s, Reportees City Count = %d "
                        ,entry.getKey()
                        ,r.getMngr_info()[3]
                        ,cityCount));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

for the given sample data, the output will be

```
Finding Managers with reportees in more tha 1 city
Found Manager Id = e2 , Mngr Phone = phone-2, Reportees City Count = 2 
Done
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `e1` should also be in the output because we need to check the entire direct report hierarchy under the manager not just the immediate employees under the manager

Answer (score 0):

Done it with an employee class and java 8 way:

```
public class EmployeePhoneNums {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        List<Employee> emps2 = List.of(
                new Employee("e1", "e1", "SF", "phone-1"),
                new Employee("e2", "e1", "SF", "phone-2"),
                new Employee("e3", "e1", "SF", "phone-3"),
                new Employee("e4", "e2", "SF", "phone-4"),
                new Employee("e5", "e2", "PH", "phone-5"),
                new Employee("e6", "e3", "NY", "phone-6"));
        Map<String, String> managerPhoneNums = emps2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpolyeeId, Employee::getPhoneNumber));
        Map<String, Set<String>> managerAndCityOfEmployee = emps2.stream().filter(e -> !e.getEmpolyeeId().equals(e.getManagerId())).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getManagerId, Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCity, Collectors.toSet())));
        List<String> resultManager = managerAndCityOfEmployee.entrySet().stream().filter(m -> m.getValue().size() > 1).map(m -> m.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        resultManager.forEach(rm -> System.out.println(rm + " : " + managerPhoneNums.get(rm)));
    
    }
}

class Employee {
    String empolyeeId;
    String managerId;
    String city;
    String phoneNumber;
    
    public Employee(String empolyeeId, String managerId, String city, String phoneNumber) {
        super();
        this.empolyeeId = empolyeeId;
        this.managerId = managerId;
        this.city = city;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmpolyeeId() {
        return empolyeeId;
    }

    public void setEmpolyeeId(String empolyeeId) {
        this.empolyeeId = empolyeeId;
    }

    public String getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public void setManagerId(String managerId) {
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

PS: Not understand why e1 is in your output, all his employees live in SF

Comment: e1 is in the output because we need to check the entire direct report hierarchy under the manager, also am looking for solution with BFS/DFS not java 8 solution

Answer (score 0):

There are few caveats with 0(n) complexity here:

1. First note on data ordering, if it not exists 0(n) probably be unreachable.
2. Take a note on data ordering again, you have child of childs at the end and parent on top. So iteration better to start from end of array (not start), this would allow accumulation of results.

Pseudocode in C# (to demonstrate an idea)

```
string[][] emps2 = new string[][] {
    //"EmployeeID", "ManagerID", "City", "Phone number"
    new string[] {"e1", "e1", "SF", "phone-1"},
    new string[] {"e2", "e1", "SF", "phone-2"},
    new string[] {"e3", "e1", "SF", "phone-3"},
    new string[] {"e4", "e2", "SF", "phone-4"},
    new string[] {"e5", "e2", "PH", "phone-5"},
    new string[] {"e6", "e3", "NY", "phone-6"}};

//"EmployeeID", "ManagerID", "City", "Phone number"

string[][] emps3 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"e1", ""},
    new string[] {"e2", ""},
    new string[] {"e3", ""},
    new string[] {"e4", ""},
    new string[] {"e5", ""},
    new string[] {"e6", ""}
};

Dictionary<string, string> managers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = emps2.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (emps2[i][0] != emps2[i][1])
    {
        string managerId;
        if (!managers.TryGetValue(emps2[i][0], out managerId))
        {
            managers.Add(emps2[i][0], "");
        }

        string current;
        if (managers.TryGetValue(emps2[i][1], out current))
        {
            current = current + emps2[i][2] + managerId;
            managers[emps2[i][1]] = current;
        }
        else
        {
            managers.Add(emps2[i][1], emps2[i][2]);
        }
    }

}
```

Some explanations, I've started from last element and do accumulation of employee city in a separate object. On each step I check my manager and my employee in the new object and populate data (possibly can be done simpler). If I see child I append child cities to the value as well.

In result I got employees and cities where they have subordinates (as a concatenated string, but that's trivial to split, distinct and count).

TL;DR You can check dynamic programming technics/example for more details on subj.

Answer (score 0):

The collections in the `java.util` package all implement the `addAll` method in O(N) time complexity (since elements are added one-by-one rather than combining the two collections directly).

To get an O(N) solution, you need a data structure that can combine two linked lists in O(1) time which means that you need to create your own class (here is one that was prepared earlier, but is slightly over-engineered for your purposes):

```java
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * <p>A doubly linked list structure that allows elements of the given enumerated type
 * to be added to, or retrieved from, the head or tail of the list and can iterate over
 * the entire list. The structure has no capability to: remove items from the list; edit
 * the order of the list; insert items in the middle of the list; or directly access
 * elements in the middle of the list.</p>
 * 
 * <p>The structure can be accessed in Constant time to:</p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>Add an element to the head or tail;</li>
 * <li>Concatenate this list with another of the same enumerated type;</li>
 * <li>Retrieve the head or tail element of the list; and</li>
 * <li>Get the next element in the list from the iterator.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p>The structure can be accessed in Linear tile to:</p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>Query the list to see if it contains an element; and</li>
 * <li>Get a string representation of the list.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param <E>
 */
public class UnmodifiableLinkList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    /**
     * Whether elements can be removed from the list.
     */
    protected boolean isModifiable = false;

    /**
     * The wrapper for the head element of the list.
     */
    protected ListElement head = null;

    /**
     * The wrapper for the tail element of the list.
     */
    protected ListElement tail = null;

    /**
     * The number of elements in the list.
     */
    protected int size = 0;

    /**
     * A reference variable to track changes to the data structure and
     * is used to highlight concurrent modification exceptions.
     */
    protected long changes = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    /**
     * Checks whether elements can be removed from the list.
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean canRemoveElements() {
        return isModifiable;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether there are no elements in the list.
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Add an element to the head of the list.
     * 
     * @param element - The non-null element to be added.
     * @throws ConcurrentModificationException Thrown if the list is modified
     *          during the execution of this method. 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Thrown if the head of the list is connected
     *          to another list and cannot be appended to.
     */
    public void addHead( E element ) {
        if ( element == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot add a null element." );
        if ( head != null && head.getHeadwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Head element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        long change = changes;
        if ( size == 0 ) {
            head = tail = new ListElement( element );
        } else {
            ListElement le = new ListElement( element );
            le.setTailwards( head );
            head.setHeadwards( le );
            head = le;
        }
        size++;
        if ( change != changes )
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        incrementChange();
    }

    /**
     * Add an element to the tail of the list.
     * 
     * @param element - The non-null element to be added.
     * @throws ConcurrentModificationException Thrown if the list is modified
     *          during the execution of this method.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Thrown if the tail of the list is connected
     *          to another list and cannot be appended to.
     */
    public void addTail( E element ) {
        if ( element == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot add a null element." );
        if ( tail != null && tail.getTailwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Tail element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        long change = changes;
        if ( size == 0 ) {
            head = tail = new ListElement( element );
        } else {
            ListElement le = new ListElement( element );
            le.setHeadwards( tail );
            tail.setTailwards( le );
            tail = le;
        }
        size++;
        if ( change != changes )
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        incrementChange();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the head element from the list or null if the list is empty.
     * 
     * @return &lt;E&gt;
     */
    public E getHead() {
        if ( size == 0 )
            return null;
        return head.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the tail element from the list or null if the list is empty.
     * 
     * @return &lt;E&gt;
     */
    public E getTail() {
        if ( size == 0 )
            return null;
        return tail.getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element before the tail element from the list or null if
     * the list does not have at least two elements.
     * 
     * @return &lt;E&gt;
     */
    public E getPenultimateTail() {
        if ( size < 2 )
            return null;
        return tail.getHeadwards().getElement();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the list.
     * @return int
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Appends the contents of the given list to the head of this list.
     * 
     * @param list - A non-null list of the same enumerated type.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Thrown if the head of this list or the tail
     *          of the given list are connected to another list and, therefore, cannot
     *          be appended to.
     */
    public void addAllHead( UnmodifiableLinkList<E> list ) {
        if ( list == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot append a null list." );
        if ( head != null && head.getHeadwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "This list's head element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        if ( list.tail != null && list.tail.getTailwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Given list's tail element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        if ( list.size() == 0 )
            return;
        long change = changes;
        long listChange = list.changes;

        isModifiable &= list.isModifiable;

        if ( size == 0 ) {
            head = list.head;
            tail = list.tail;
            size = list.size;
        } else {
            head.setHeadwards( list.tail );
            list.tail.setTailwards( head );
            head = list.head;
            size += list.size;
        }

        list.head = list.tail = null;
        list.size = 0;

        if ( change != changes || listChange != list.changes )
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        incrementChange();
    }

    /**
     * Appends the contents of the given list to the tail of this list.
     * 
     * @param list - A non-null list of the same enumerated type.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException Thrown if the tail of this list or the head
     *          of the given list are connected to another list and, therefore, cannot
     *          be appended to.
     */
    public void addAllTail( UnmodifiableLinkList<E> list ) {
        if ( list == null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot append a null list." );
        if ( tail != null && tail.getTailwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "This list's tail element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        if ( list.head != null && list.head.getHeadwards() != null )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Given list's head element is connected to another list and cannot be appended to.");
        if ( list.size() == 0 )
            return;
        long change = changes;
        long listChange = list.changes;

        isModifiable &= list.isModifiable;

        if ( size == 0 ) {
            head = list.head;
            tail = list.tail;
            size = list.size;
        } else {
            tail.setTailwards( list.head );
            list.head.setHeadwards( tail );
            tail = list.tail;
            size += list.size;
        }

        list.head = list.tail = null;
        list.size = 0;

        if ( change != changes || listChange != list.changes )
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        incrementChange();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether a given element is contained within the list.
     * @param element - The element to locate in the list. 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean contains( final E element ) {
        return findElement( element ) != null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the internal list data structure containing the given element
     * within the list. 
     * @param element - The element to locate in the list.
     * @return ListElement
     */
    protected ListElement findElement( final E element ) {
        ListElement current = head;
        while ( current != null ) {
            if ( current.getElement() == element )
                return current;
            current = current.getTailwards();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a comma-space separated sequence representing the contents
     * of the list. The return value is bracketed by angle brackets (<>). 
     * @see UnmodifiableLinkList#toString(String) toString( String )
     * @return String 
     */
    public String toString() {
        return toString( ", " );
    }

    /**
     * Returns a sequence representing the contents of the list. The return
     * value is bracketed by angle brackets (<>) and pairs of elements are
     * separated by the value of the function's separator argument. 
     * @param separator - A string defining the separator between list
     *          elements.
     * @return String
     */
    public String toString( String separator ) {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        b.append( '<' );
        boolean first = true;
        for ( E e: this ) {
            if ( first )
                first = false;
            else
                b.append( separator );
            b.append( e );
        }
        b.append( '>' );
        return b.toString();
        
    }

    /**
     * <p>Increments the counter recording the number of changes to the
     * data structure.</p>
     * <p>Used as a simple (imperfect) method to detect concurrent
     * modification of a list.</p>
     */
    protected synchronized void incrementChange() {
        if ( changes == Long.MAX_VALUE )
            changes = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        else
            changes++;
    }

    /**
     * <p>The data structure used to store a single element of data within
     * the list</p>
     */
    protected class ListElement {
        private E element;
        private ListElement tailwards = null;
        private ListElement headwards = null;

        protected ListElement( E element ) {
            this.element = element;
        }

        protected void setElement( E element )          { this.element = element; }
        protected void setTailwards( ListElement next ) { this.tailwards = next; }
        protected void setHeadwards( ListElement prev ) { this.headwards = prev; }

        protected E getElement()    { return element; }
        protected ListElement getTailwards()    { return tailwards; }
        protected ListElement getHeadwards()    { return headwards; }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator to loop through the list from head-to-tail.
     * @return Iterator<E>
     */
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            ListElement current = head;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != null;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if ( current == null )
                    return null;
                E next = current.getElement();
                current = current.getTailwards();
                return next;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot remove from this list." );
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator to loop through the list from tail-to-head.
     * @return Iterator<E>
     */
    public Iterator<E> reverseIterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            ListElement current = tail;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != null;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if ( current == null )
                    return null;
                E next = current.getElement();
                current = current.getHeadwards();
                return next;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot remove from this list." );
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you can implement an O(N) depth-first solution using:

```java
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Employee
{
    private static UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> ALL_EMPLOYEES
        = new UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee>();

    private String   id;
    private Employee manager;
    private String   city;
    private UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> reports;
    private String   phone;

    public Employee(
        final String   id,
        final Employee manager,
        final String   city,
        final String   phone
    )
    {
        this.id      = id;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.city    = city;
        this.phone   = phone;
        this.reports = new UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee>();
        if (this.manager != null)
        {
            this.manager.reports.addTail(this);
        }
        ALL_EMPLOYEES.addTail(this);
    }

    public boolean hasReportsInDifferentCities()
    {
        Iterator<Employee> reportIterator = this.reports.iterator();
        if (!reportIterator.hasNext())
        {
            return false;
        }
        String city = reportIterator.next().city;
        while (reportIterator.hasNext())
        {
            if (city != reportIterator.next().city)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> dfs()
    {
        UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> matches = new UnmodifiableLinkList<>();
        for (final Employee employee: this.reports)
        {
            UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> empMatches = employee.dfs();
            if (!empMatches.isEmpty())
            {
                matches.addAllTail(empMatches);
            }
        }
        if (!matches.isEmpty() || this.hasReportsInDifferentCities())
        {
            matches.addHead(this);
        }
        return matches;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.id + ": " + this.phone;
    }

    public static void main(
        final String[] args
    )
    {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("e1", null, "SF", "phone-1");
        Employee e2 = new Employee("e2", e1, "SF", "phone-2");
        Employee e3 = new Employee("e3", e1, "SF", "phone-3");
        new Employee("e4", e2, "SF", "phone-4");
        new Employee("e5", e2, "PH", "phone-5");
        new Employee("e6", e3, "NY", "phone-6");

        for (Employee employee: ALL_EMPLOYEES)
        {
            if (employee.manager == null)
            {
                // Root of the hierarchy
                UnmodifiableLinkList<Employee> matches = employee.dfs();
                System.out.println(matches);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> <e1: phone-1, e2: phone-2>
> ```

---

#### Time Complexity:

- The `hasReportsInDifferentCities` method will iterate over each `report` for that Employee so, for an individual employee is `O(R)` where `R` is the number of reports. However, for each tree hierarchy of employees, there are `T` employees in the tree and there will be `1` top level manager and `T-1` reportees and each reportee only has a single manager; therefore, when traversing the entire tree the `hasReportsInDifferentCities` method will be called `T` times and iterates over each of the `T-1` relationships between manager-and-reportees only once and therefore to process the entire tree the complexity is O(T) [and the average time complexity of a call to the `hasReportsInDifferentCities` method when amortised over the entire tree is O(1)].
- Similarly, the `dfs` method will, for each Employee, iterate over its `report` and for `R` reportees will be O(R); however, with exactly the same logic as above, for a tree the `T` employees the total number of reports will be `T-1` then for each Employee to iterate over its reports once to perform the DFS and then potentially a second time in a call to `hasReportsInDifferentCities` will mean that each of the `T-1` manager-reportee relationships will be processed at most twice and the total time complexity of processing the entire tree is O(T) [and, similarly, the average time complexity of a call to the `dfs` method when amortised over the entire tree is O(1)].
- The `main` method will:

  - create `N` employees each in constant time for a total of O(N).
  - loop through all `N` employees and call the `dfs` method only if the employee is a top-level manager splitting the employees up into a forest of trees (in this case, a single tree but there is the potential for multiple disjoint trees). If the N employees are split into disjoint trees with the number of employees T<sub>1</sub> ... T<sub>m</sub> then Σ<sub>k=1..m</sub>T = N and given that the `dfs` function for T employees has the time complexity O(T) then the total time complexity for processing all the trees will be O(N).

Comment: This is O(n2), because `hasReportsInDifferentCities()` is O(n) and it is executed n times (once for every Employee)

Comment: @Bohemian No, `hasReportsInDifferentCities()` is O(N) for any individual Employee but across all N employees, given that the OP's data is a tree, there can only be N-1 reportees  (the other one is the top-level manager) in total so that when run for all Employees across the entire data-set it will also be O(N) (and not O(N²).

Comment: @Bohemian I've updated the answer to include a more complete analysis of the time complexity and that for both `hasReportsInDifferentCities()` and `dfs()` then when called for each employee have a maximum time-complexity of O(R) for R reportees but when amortised over the entire tree will have an average time complexity that is O(1) which gives a total time complexity for processing the entire tree that is O(N) for a total of N employees.